# PHP Deprecated: Methods with the same name password hash

Tags: php

error password hash line 1 class passwordhash

PHP Deprecated:  Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; PasswordHash has a deprecated constructor
how to fix error?
my database 7.1

```
class PasswordHash {
var $itoa64;
var $iteration_count_log2;
var $portable_hashes;
var $random_state;
var $hash_method; // do not modify directly, use set_hash_method instead.

function PasswordHash($iteration_count_log2 = 9, $portable_hashes = false, $hash_method = null, $full_compat = true)
{
    $this->portable_hashes = $portable_hashes;
    $this->full_compat = $full_compat;

    if ($this->set_hash_method($hash_method)===false){
        return false;
    }
    $this->itoa64 = './0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    if ($iteration_count_log2 < 4 || $iteration_count_log2 > 31)
        $iteration_count_log2 = 8;
    $this->iteration_count_log2 = $iteration_count_log2;
    $this->random_state = microtime();
    if (function_exists('getmypid'))
        $this->random_state .= getmypid();

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: in php class constructors does not have same as class name, simply replace `function PasswordHash` with `public function __construct`

Comment: guys, let's vote for close this question. it's too simple, dump and too broad

Comment: PHP does have a fairly comprehensive online manual, you know.  I'd recommend you read it for stuff like this.

Comment: read this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I don't know which version of PHP you are using but the WARNING message is telling you that you should stop using constructors with the same name of the class and start using `__construct` instead.

```
class PasswordHash {
var $itoa64;
var $iteration_count_log2;
var $portable_hashes;
var $random_state;
var $hash_method; // do not modify directly, use set_hash_method instead.

function __construct($iteration_count_log2 = 9, $portable_hashes = false, 
    $hash_method = null, $full_compat = true) {
...
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP 4 constructors had the same name as a class. Since PHP7 it is not an option.
You should rename method with name PasswordHash.
And also constructor doesn't return value.

Comment: sorry Dmitry to interrupt, but You must agree that there are tons of such questions with answers and it's too simple - not Your level to respond to ones who lazy to understand from simple english sentence: `Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP` and just simply go and read http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php about class constructors